# Passing user id argument to filter

Tags: views

I have a view that lists the (ubercart) orders of a user. I created a view for that with a filter applied: "User: current". This works perfectly this way, I use this view in my profile page template like this:

```
$view = views_get_view('user_orders_custom');
$result = $view->execute_display('default', array($account->uid));
```

My problem is that when admin is inspecting the profile page of a user, this lists the orders of the admin, not the user being watched. Of course the passed $account->uid is not used by the applied views filter `User:current`.

I don't know how to make my view filter on the **passed uid**. I tried creating a relationship, arguments but the filter thing is not clear to me.

Comment: the question is still open, any help appreciated.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: removing filter `User:current` and adding argument `(Order user) Ubercart order: User ID`.

Answer (score 1):

May be what you need is [contextual filters](http://drupal.org/node/1166072), the user can go to `view-name/%` where *%* is a contextual filter for the *uid*

Comment: Not exactly, but thanks for the tip. I forgot to mention that I am using Drupal 6 where this module is not available afaik.

Comment: @jabal: oh, I am a bit of drupal 7 only. But I think [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) might help.